# PPPoE vs L2TP protocols

Tags: vpn, pppoe, l2tp

I am trying to find differences between PPPoE and L2TP.Both are tunneling protocols. When to use what?

thanks,
GL

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 9):

The most and noticeable different is layer of tunneling. `PPPOE` is a Layer 2 (Data Link Layer) tunneling protocol while `L2TP` is a Layer 3 (Network Layer) tunneling protocol. This means that `PPPOE` can create a tunnel between devices in a broadcast domain (such as devices connect to the same switch) but `L2TP` can create a tunnel between two IP-based device anywhere in the world (if they are reachable from each other).

Suppose there are two computer A and B which are connected to a R:

> A <------> R <--------> B

A cannot tunnels to B using `PPPOE` because A and B are not in the same broadcast domain but a tunnel could be created using `L2TP` protocol.

Other differences are in authentication and encryption methods which `L2TP` is more flexible in authentication and is more secure in encryption.